# Distributing an average over a date range

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to generate a graph based on a date range(X axis) and an average class size (Y axis) which occurs at the midpoint of the date range. Also known variable is the minimum class size at the start and end of the date range.

I'm trying to generate the points in between so that the graph peaks out at the middle and spreads across the date range to the minimum class size at the start/end of the date range.

I tried it in excel and got a binomial equation. Is there a way to do it other than that?

Sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com as opposed to math.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $Y=Y_{max}Exp(-\frac{(X-X_{Mid})^2}{2 \sigma^2})$. Choose $\sigma^2$ so the end point is correct.  $\sigma^2=\frac{(X_{start}-X_{Mid})^2}{2Log_e(Y_{Max}/Y_{Min})}$. This is obviously inspired by the normal distribution.